# Ruby on rails 3 - Rendering edit form instead of a new form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, new-operator, render, edit

Hi
Im creating a comments feature on my application, but when a user have added a comment and I render the new comment page with *.js.erb file it renders a "edit" form for the comment the user just posted?

```
$('#pager').append("<%= escape_javascript(render :new) %>");
```

Controller edit & new for comment looks like this.

```
      # GET /comments/new
  # GET /comments/new.xml
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml { render :xml => @comment }
    end
  end

  # GET /comments/1/edit
  def edit
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The *new* action will get run when you browse to add a comment.  The *create* action is generally run after a user clicks submit's from the *new* form.

Look in the *create* action to see what view is getting rendered after submission.

Comment: Hi,
Yeah, well I thought this was the trick... I have the create and it's remote with render of a create.js.erb file.

This is the code 

$('#new_comment').remove();
$('#pager').append("<%= escape_javascript(render :new) %>");
$('#new_comment').slideDown();